# Splitting a string of values into multiple strings

Tags: python, string, list, indexing, split

I'm currently working on a program that takes a group of lists from a csv file, and groups them together. The program I came up with is:

```
List_one = []                  
with open("trees.csv") as f:    
    skiplines = f.readline()    
    for line in f:
          res = line.split(" ")    
          List_one.append(res)      
    for i in List_one:
        (i[0]) = (i[0]).rstrip("\n")    
print (List_one)
```

What I get now are a group of lists, but the problem is that these lists are strings and I want them as floats. The lists look like this:

```
[['1,8.3,70,10.3'], ['2,8.6,65,10.3'], ['3,8.8,63,10.2'], ['4,10.5,72,16.4'], ['5,10.7,81,18.8'], ['6,10.8,83,19.7'], ['7,11.0,66,15.6'], ['8,11.0,75,18.2'], ['9,11.1,80,22.6'], ['10,11.2,75,19.9'], ['11,11.3,79,24.2'], ['12,11.4,76,21.0'], ['13,11.4,76,21.4'], ['14,11.7,69,21.3'], ['15,12.0,75,19.1'], ['16,12.9,74,22.2'], ['17,12.9,85,33.8'], ['18,13.3,86,27.4'], ['19,13.7,71,25.7'], ['20,13.8,64,24.9'], ['21,14.0,78,34.5'], ['22,14.2,80,31.7'], ['23,14.5,74,36.3'], ['24,16.0,72,38.3'], ['25,16.3,77,42.6'], ['26,17.3,81,55.4'], ['27,17.5,82,55.7'], ['28,17.9,80,58.3'], ['29,18.0,80,51.5'], ['30,18.0,80,51.0'], ['31,20.6,87,77.0']]
```

As you guys can see I also can't use float() on list one either, because the list is a whole string on its own. Is there a way I can split the lists by indexing so I get:

```
['1', '8.3', '70', '10.3'].....
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: `res = line.split(",")`

Answer (score 0):

"line.split(',')" split the string with "," and returns list.
for string '1,8.3,70,10.3' it will return [1, 8.3, 70, 10.3]

Answer (score 0):

You can split the strings by the commas if you want. You should probably do everything before you append them to List_one though.

```
res = [float(x) for x in line.split(" ")[0].split(",")]
List_one.append(res)
```

Does this work how you want it to? Sorry I'm not sure what format the input is in so I'm kind of guessing

Answer (score 0):

You could say:

```
res = line.split(" ")

# map takes a function as the first arg and a list as the second
list_of_floats = list(map(lambda n: float(n), res.split(",")))

# then you can
List_one.append(list_of_floats)
```

Which will still give you a nested list because you are pushing a list during each iteration of `for line in f:`, but each list would at least be floats as you've specified.

If you wanted to just get one flat list of floats instead of doing the initial `line.split(' ')` you could use regex to split the line read from the csv:

```
import re # at the top of your file

res = re.split(r'[\s\,]', line)
list_of_floats = list(map(lambda n: float(n), res))
List_one.append(list_of_floats)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
l =[['1,8.3,70,10.3'], ['2,8.6,65,10.3'], ['3,8.8,63,10.2'], ['4,10.5,72,16.4']]

l2 =[]
for x in l:
    a =x[0].split(",")
    l2.append(a)
print(l2)
```

Enjoy!